# What official statements have Seo Kouji's studio made regarding Akitsuki Fuuka's fate, and what were the repercussions of said statements?

Tags: fuuka, kouji-seo

Wherever there is internet and controversial plot twists, there shall be rage, angst and trolling.

Trying to sift through the comment threads in /r/anime and other places is really a pain, and somewhere I end up bouncing on the language barrier.

Doing what they did to the title character so early surely was controversial, and it seems it was not an event planned from the beginning of the series.

What has Seo Kouji stated regarding

> Akitsuki Fuuka's death

and how were those statements received? What were the repercussions in specialized media?